# Stop background music

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, media-player, avfoundation

I have this app that has several view controllers. In the app delegate, I set it so that as soon as the app finishes launching, the background music starts. However, on another view controller, I have this button that plays this video. My problem is that when I play the movie, the background audio overlaps with the movie. My question is, how do I stop the music when I play the movie and play the music after the movie ends.
Here is my app_delegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface App_Delegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

Here is my App_Delegate.m

```
#import "App_Delegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation App_Delegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    {NSString* soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beethoven_sym_5_i" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL* soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
        AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        player.numberOfLoops=-1;
        [player play];
    }


    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the navigation controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

My MovieViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MovieViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *sesamescroller;
}

- (IBAction)playsesamemovie:(id)sender;


@end
```

Finally, my MovieViewController.m

```
#import "MovieViewController.h"


@interface MovieViewController ()

@end

@implementation MovieViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad


- (void)viewDidUnload


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)playsesamemovie:(id)sender {
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"How to make Sesame chicken" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}


- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [sesamescroller release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you show has a local variable pointing to the `player` object. To control the player, other code needs to be able to find it. Like this:

In `App_Delegate.h`:

```
@property (strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

in `App_Delegate.m`: (where did this underbar come from? Most unconventional!)

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
self.player.numberOfLoops=-1;
[self.player play];
```

Then, wherever you want to control it:

```
[((App_Delegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).player pause];
// ...
[((App_Delegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).player play];
```

Comment: Error: property "player" not found on object of type  'id <UIApplicationDelegate>'

Comment: Sorry, more brackets needed. I added them to those two lines of code in the answer above.

Comment: How to play again after movie playback completes?

Comment: That's what the line above that says `player play];` does.

Comment: Where do I add the line of code? I want it to play after movie view closes. Should put behind "Movie Playback Complete" line?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. After clicking done, and the movie player closes, the music doesn't start. Any idea why?

Comment: Does `moviePlayerComplete` execute at all if you don't actually complete playing the movie? Put an `NSLog()` in there?

Comment: Good point. If the movie actually does finish playing all the way, the music will play, but I'm trying to say that how would I start it again if instead of finishing the whole movie, they click the done button. How would I play the music again.

Comment: You need to check MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html . I suggest you ask another question if that isn't clear, this comment thread is getting rather long.

Answer (score 2):

```
 set scalling mode to your player

for Paused :
 [moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused];

 for Stopped:
 [moviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped];
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible on iOS, you can use scriptable feature to send message to mute. I did this sometime back for Mac OS X where I used to control iTunes from another app.

Comment: Search for "Scripting Bridge Programming Guide"

Answer (score 0):

## First add start to songs in application delegate

*.h application delegate*

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
 @class ViewController;
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
    NSDictionary *config;
   NSMutableArray *ARRAY;

}
-(void)stop;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSDictionary *config;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

*.m application delegate*

```
  @implementation AppDelegate
  {
      AVAudioPlayer*  audioPlayer;
  }
  @synthesize myAudioPlayer;
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
      audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =  1;
      audioPlayer.delegate=self;
      [audioPlayer play];
 }
 -(void)stop
 {
     [audioPlayer stop];

 }
 -(void)star
 {
     [audioPlayer play];

 }
```

## when use required start and stop background music in application

## directly call this  method -start and -stop

## ..it really work